# Cannot ping OpenVPN IP ranges from clients

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have OpenVPN 2.3.10 running on my server Ubuntu 16.04, it starts fine and clients connect fine, I just can't seem to get my clients to be able to ping the server or other clients IP.

Clients are using Viscocity 1.7.6.

Here is my server config:

```
# Port Number.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server.
proto udp

# Interface type, TUN or TAP.
dev tun

# Certificates.
ca ca.crt
cert SERVERNAME.crt
key SERVERNAME.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
dh dh2048.pem

# Subnet to use for OpenVPN Connections.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Keepalive: send ping every 10 seconds, tunnel down after 120 seconds no response.
keepalive 10 120

# LZO Compression for the tunnel.
comp-lzo

# Drop privileges to user/group nobody.
user root
group root

# Makes the link more resistant to connection failures.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Username and Password authentication.
client-cert-not-required
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login

# OpenVPN Status Log files.
status openvpn-status.log

# LOG FILE VERBOSITY:
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 6
#log-append /var/log/openvpn.log

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"

client-to-client

username-as-common-name
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

And here is my Viscocity client config:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried TAP as well as TUN. With TAP I can now ping my local other VPN units, but no longer have internet.

What I want to achieve is internet through the clients local network, so no VPN routing for internet, but I want all clients to be able to communicate for windows networking.

I've also tried this:

[image]

That doesn't do anything. The tun device is there and I've got an IP:

[image]

Comment: How is the firewall configured on the OpenVPN server? The trouble is most likely there.

Comment: Firewall IPTables is disabled on the VPN server, not running. The fact that if I enable TAP I can ping the server and VPN clients but not internet, but with TUN I can only internet, tells me it's not firewall.